# Timeout connecting to AKS cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

kubectl commands (kubectl get nodes, kubectl cluster-info dump) are failing again all of a sudden in powershell, bash, and the azure cloud shell with the following error:

> Error from server (Timeout): the server was unable to return a
>   response in the time allotted, but may still be processing the request

Comment: could you tell me your AKS cluster location? can you connect to it now?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT the region the cluster is in is EastUS. I just tried to connect again and it worked. What was the issue? That was a long time to be down and we were forced to spin up another cluster and all associated deployments to it.

Comment: Sorry to give you a bad experience, AKS still in preview:)